# Remote Powershell code blocks execute in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell, powershell-remoting

Could somebody help with understanding multithreading in remote powershell?
I am trying to copy a file to remote computer using only WinRM. Here is the algorithm:

1. Divide local file to byte[] chunks.
2. Every chunk is base64 encoded.
3. base64 string sent to remote WinRM in a powershell code block, which decodes it and appends to file.
4. Remote file eventually filled with all bytes and is an exact copy of local file.

The problem is that I get "The process cannot access the file, because it is used by another process" type of errors when executing remote powershell blocks. It looks like powershell executes my script blocks in parallel. But I need sequential execution. Can I override this?

Full code example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/anuriq/5ae05b20008602b5f10b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you create a remote PowerShell session, it is using a different PowerShell process to execute the request.  This is why you are running into file contention issues.  You should consider using the same remote session for each operation rather than creating a new one each time you want to append a chunk.

BTW if you are on (or when you get to) V5, you can use `$s = New-PSSession remoteComputerName; Copy-Item src.txt C:\dst.txt -ToSession $s` to copy a file to a remote computer.

Comment: Thanks Keith. About V5: I want to be able to run this code at least on V3.
   "You should consider using the same remote session for each operation rather than creating a new one each time you want to append a chunk." - could you advise how to do that?

Comment: Move the PowerShell.Create code which initializes a PowerShell object with a runspace, out of the appendContent method and instead of passing a Runspace to appendContent, pass the PowerShell object that you created.  In fact, you could make this perform faster by calling the code that opens the file and creates the `$fs` variable in an init method.  When you provide the same PowerShell session to appendContent, `$fs` will still be defined.  You can execute the one line `$fs.Write(...)`.  Then after all the bytes have been written, use another method to close the file.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I've refactored code using your advises. In this version, process overlap also occurs, but rarely and for large files only (> 37 MB i divide them). So it is possible to catch and retry. Example available [here](https://gist.github.com/anuriq/1d787e0defeb0268f60d).